# Display output of command executed in bash as it is executing

Tags: bash, scripts

I've got a line in my bash script like this:

```
echo "`some_command`"
```

Now, `some_command` executes for around 1-2mins and it keeps printing alerts/messages in that interval.

Problem is when I execute my bash script, the script has no output for 1-2mins and then directly displays the output after complete execution of `some_command`.

How can I make my bash script output `some_command` as it is executing? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Just run the command?

Comment: It would be better if you could paste the commands you are running.

Comment: @fkraiem - I need to perform certain checks before I can execute the command.

Comment: @Rooney - The command which I'm using is a Python script. I'm calling just one command and then the Python script performs it's task.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `some_command` in a command substitution and `echo`ing the result? Just execute `some_command` directly.

Comment: You can simply put an 'echo line' before the executing line: `echo "some command"` or `echo "This command is running now ... (please wait for it to finish)"` , which will print the information you want (in the terminal window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
echo "`some_command`"
```

With:

```
some_command
```

The backticks aren't useful here, so can be dispensed with.  They'd only be good if the thing needed was to somehow summarize the output *after* it was completed.

Answer (score 1):

#### xtrace

You could set the [`xtrace`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) option (commonly used for debugging shell scripts) before running the command (no need to use command substitution). Also, don’t forget to unset the option afterwards.

```
set -x
some_command
set +x
```

Example:

```
$ set -x; sleep 2 && echo fin; set +x
+ sleep 2
+ echo fin
fin
+ set +x
```

---

#### echo

If you find the xtrace output to be too cluttered, you could simply `echo` the name of the command beforehand:

```
echo some_command
some_command
```